# How to create a VCD from MP4 files on Windows XP?

Tags: burning, mp4, mpg, vcd

I've got a Flip video recorder and want to put the videos from it onto CD so that they can be played in a standard DVD player. (I can't make DVDs, as I only have a CD burner.) I've exported the videos from Flip to MP4 files and figured I could use Windows Media Player 11 (in XP) to burn them to a VCD. However, when I try to play the files in WMP, it complains that they're of zero length.

I'm hoping that if I convert them to .MPG format, I might have a bit more luck. Is there a simple way to do this without installing anything of dubious quality on my PC? (I'm keen to avoid spyware, etc.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Depending upon what burning software you have:

http://www.ehow.com/how_5017127_convert-vcd-using-hand-brake.html

Maybe this:

http://www.videohelp.com/tools/The_FilmMachine

These days, VCDs are a pain. There are a few other tools kicking around, but they haven't been updated in quite some time.  Which leads me to the next suggestion.

It may be time to invest in a DVD drive at this point, since they're fairly inexpensive.

SATA DVD Burner ($20, free shipping): http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16827106289

Or

IDE DVD Burner ($24, $4 shipping): http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16827106281

And

TDK 50-pack of DVD-R's ($10, free shipping): http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817131595

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [MediaCoder](http://www.mediacoderhq.com/index.htm).

> MediaCoder is a **free** universal media
>   transcoder since 2005. It integrates
>   most popular audio/video codecs and
>   tools in an elegant and transparent
>   manner into an all-in-one transcoding
>   solution.

Answer (score 0):

Super(c) will convert just about anything to anything.

http://www.erightsoft.com/SUPER.html